# Conflicting API when trying to run MRUnit example

Tags: java, hadoop, junit, mrunit

I've been playing around with MRUnit and tried running it for a hadoop wordcount example following the tutorial for [wordcount](http://learnhadoopwithme.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/hello-world-of-mapreduce-word-count/) and [unit testing](http://learnhadoopwithme.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/unit-test-mapreduce-using-mrunit/)

Though not a fan, I've been using Eclipse to run the code and I keep getting an error for setMapper function

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;


import org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.MapDriver;
import org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.MapReduceDriver;
import org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.ReduceDriver;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestWordCount {
  MapReduceDriver<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> mapReduceDriver;
  MapDriver<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> mapDriver;
  ReduceDriver<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> reduceDriver;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws IOException
  {
      WordCountMapper mapper = new WordCountMapper();
      mapDriver = new MapDriver<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>();
      mapDriver.setMapper(mapper);  //<--Issue here

      WordCountReducer reducer = new WordCountReducer();
      reduceDriver = new ReduceDriver<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>();
      reduceDriver.setReducer(reducer);

      mapReduceDriver = new MapReduceDriver<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable,     Text, IntWritable>();
      mapReduceDriver.setMapper(mapper); //<--Issue here
      mapReduceDriver.setReducer(reducer);
  }
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method setMapper(Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>) in the type MapDriver<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> is not applicable for the arguments (WordCountMapper)
    The method setMapper(Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>) in the type MapReduceDriver<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> is not applicable for the arguments (WordCountMapper)
```

Looking up this issue, I think it might be an API conflict but I'm not sure where to look for it. Anybody else have this issue before?

*EDIT* I'm using a user defined library with the hadoop2 jar and the latest Junit(4.10) jar in it.

*EDIT 2* Here is the code for WordCountMapper

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();


    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}
```

*FINAL EDIT / IT WORKS*

Turns out I needed to set

```
WordCountMapper mapper = new WordCountMapper();
```

to

```
Mapper mapper = new WordCountMapper();
```

since there was an issue with generics. Also needed to import the mockito library into my user defined library.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem

```
public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>
....
MapDriver<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> mapDriver;
```

Your `WordCountMapper` input type (`Object`) is not compatible with the `MapDriver` input type (`LongWritable`).  Change your `Mapper` definition to

```
class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
```

You probably want to change your `map` method argument from `Object key` to `LongWritable key` also.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have imported correct class, i have faced same error unlike above my program was having correct parameters in both classes Reducer and reduce_test but due to importing wrong class i have faced same error message which is reported above

Wrongly imported class--

import org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.ReduceDriver;

Correct class---

import org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.ReduceDriver;

same solution in case of mapper_test, if you are sure that your parameters are same in Mapper__class and Mapper_test